# Hiding elements in iFrames

Tags: javascript, iframe, bootstrap-4

Below is my attempt of trying to hide my `jumbotron` class in the `iframe` with Javascript. I've had no luck!

The error in my console is:

> Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

I can't understand why it's not working - sorry if I'm being stupid here, really not the best at Javascript. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("jumbotron")[0];
elmnt.style.display = "none";
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-8">
      <iframe id="myFrame" style="" width="100%" border="0" frameborder="0" src="https://remelo.com/booking/c/1/remelo" height="789"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are the main page and the iframe page at the same domain? If they are not, you can't access elements on the third party page. If they are at the same domain, have you waited for the iframe to finish loading?

Comment: If that's the case, you've answered my question. It's cross-domain... Thank you!